# Android Automatically open a Webpage using Chrome on boot

Tags: boot

I have an Android TV box plugged on a TV in a waiting room.

I would like to have a web page open on Chrome automatically when I turn it on.

Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried one of the "Kiosk mode" apps from Google Play Store?

Comment: Hello @Robert, I didn't know about these "Kiosk" apps until you told me, I've tried one and it seems to be exactly what I am looking for, thanks a lot!